# Strategies reading large data from Microsoft CSV and writing to Microsoft Excel in AWS

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, lambda

Kindly assist in deciding the strategy to do Extraction, Transformation and Loading (ETL) work flow with Amazon AWS offerings. I am a newbie in Amazon Cloud. My use case is to read thousands of record rows from Microsoft CSV file. My intention is to write out this file into Microsoft Excel document. I want to store this excel file in single piece within S3 bucket as an object.
Currently, I am doing this proof of concept with AWS Lambda. My issue is /tmp size is exceeding beyond 512 MB even if I select 6 GB RAM size in lambda specification. I do not do any disk operation. I read all of S3 csv file content once, in RAM and write out to excel, in RAM.

Comment: Can you please check container lambdas. They have 10GB of space.

Comment: Existing lambda from Dec-20 also offer 10 GB

Comment: I mean 10GB of disk space. Existing lambda offer only 10 GB of ram and 512 MB disk space.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using aws glue for large volume data transformations. Lambda may be Ill suited to the task

Comment: We are doing aws glue work flow. I cannot export to Microsoft excel from both AWS Glue and AWS Athena

Comment: You can do it in the python environment of glue. Do not use pyspark. U will need to do the transformation using pandas.